# Initializing JsonSerializerOptions with Converters

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I would like to create a static instance of [JsonSerializerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=netcore-3.1) from System.Text.Json. This instance should have a custom list of Converters. So, my inclination:

```
static readonly JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    // Error - Converters cannot be assigned to
    Converters = new[] { new DateTimeOffsetConverter() }
};
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#registration-sample---converters-collection) show using `Add` to add a Converter once the instance exists, like:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverter());
```

Any elegant ideas to do this for a static field?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C#'s initializer syntax will actually call "Add" if you just use braces:

```
static readonly JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new DateTimeOffsetConverter() }
}
```

You could also use a static initializer:

```
static readonly JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

static MyClass(){
    serializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverter())
}
```

Comment: Hot damn! I was hoping that existed. Thanks, works like a charm.